# Inbox showing date instead of time

Tags: sms, htc-one, date-and-time

My SMS inbox suddenly began to display the date instead of the time. Previously it has shown for example 18:54, but now it says OKT. 27 in the inbox.  When I open a conversation it will now say 27/10/2013, 18:54, instead of just 18:54.

How can I get it back to how it was?

Comment: Have you checked the Messaging app's settings?